# Why id() for same Unicode string literals gives different result?

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, unicode-literals

Why Unicode string literals show different id's ? I was hoping the same behavior as that of String literals.

```
>>> p = 'abcd'
>>> q = 'abcd'
>>> id(p) == id(q)
True
>>> p = u'abcd'
>>> q = u'abcd'
>>> id(p) == id(q)
False
```

Please provide some pointers on this.

Answer (score 0):

For the same reason two `dict`s with the same contents would have different `id`s: they are distinct objects.  I suspect that the non-Unicode string literals being the same object is something of an optimization.